# Add a string of text before or after a sentence using sed

Tags: sed

I have this pattern:

```
cute, playful and lively dog.
```

I want to add words in the beginning of a sentence so it looks like.

```
adorable, cuddly, cute, playful and lively dog.
```

How do I do this using sed?

Answer (score 2):

Below command would replace the start of the line boundary with `adorable, cuddly,` which inturn prepends the text at the start.

```
sed 's/^/adorable, cuddly, /' file
```